# What does __ (two underscores) stand for in Hpux C program

Tags: c++, c, hp-ux, acc

I see the following code in HPUX C program:

```
   extern int fcntl __((int, int, ...));
   _LF_EXTERN int creat __((const char *, mode_t));
```

These lines are compiled using aCC.

Could somebody let me know the meaning of 2 underscores after `fcntl` and `creat` in the above code?

Comment: I suspect this to be a macro function. Can you show the preprocessed version of this code?

Comment: The duplicates are wrong, but be it as it may. I've seen something similar e.g. in the readline library sourcecode to distinct between old-style declarations/definitions and prototypes. So, on a "modern" (not older than ~30 years) system, it will expand to `(int, int, ...)`, on old systems to `()`. HTH, just a shot in the dark, though.

Comment: The duplicates were indeed wrong.

Comment: It's probably defined as a macro. Look for `#define __` (with optional whitespace inserted) somewhere in header files included by that file.

Answer (score 6):

This is most likely a macro that enables the use of the header with old, pre-ANSI C compilers.
The "old style" C function declarations didn't include parameter types.

I suspect its definition looks somewhat like this

```
#ifdef __STDC__
#define __(params) params
#else
#define __(params) ()
#endif
```

I believe type-safe function prototypes is one of the first language features that C adopted from C++.
And the fact that I remember this makes me feel very, very old.

Comment: It was quite common to see the single-underscore macro used for this purpose too.